# xcode build error: project does not contain a scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcodebuild

I am developing a ionic application but when I am trying to build it it is giving me below error

```
xcodebuild: error: The project named "SnapHome" does not contain a scheme named "SnapHome". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the project.
```

Below is the available schemes

```
Information about workspace "SnapHome":
    Schemes:
        SnapHome
```

I am using below script and **enterprise provisioning profile** to build the application, I have used same script to build other cordova applications

```
cordova build
projectname='xxxxx'
provisionprofilename="xxxxxxx"
outoutdirectory="xxxxxxx"
xcodeprojectdirectory="yyyyyy/snapapp/platforms/ios"

rm -f "$outoutdirectory"/"$projectname".xcarchive
rm -f "$outoutdirectory"/"$projectname".ipa

xcodebuild clean -project "$xcodeprojectdirectory"/"$projectname".xcodeproj -configuration Release -alltargets

xcodebuild -workspace "$xcodeprojectdirectory"/"$projectname".xcworkspace -list

xcodebuild archive -project "$xcodeprojectdirectory"/"$projectname".xcodeproj -scheme "$projectname" -archivePath "$outoutdirectory"/"$projectname".xcarchive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "$outoutdirectory"/"$projectname".xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportPlist.plist -exportPath "$outoutdirectory"/"$projectname".ipa
```

Could you please let me know what is the issue and how to fix this. I am using xcode 8.3.2

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem on my build, and just checking the `Shared` option on the Product > Scheme > `Edit Scheme` was not actually adding the scheme to Source control.

What happens is that when you share the scheme xcode will copy the scheme from the local user `xcuserdata` to a new folder `xcshareddata/scschemes` under the `.xcodeproj` but when you commit and push the change this new folder is not included by default and you need to force the commit.
Once I forced the commit of the new `xcsharedata/xcshemes` folder, the build server could now find the scheme successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First I shared the scheme om the Edit Scheme screen, after that I added the xcshareddata/schemes to my commit and pushed to the server. This make the scheme available on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by sharing the scheme. it is available from Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Shared [check box] in the bottom pannel

[image: Location of Shared check box]